# UWP: Is it possible to create a "personal" app?

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Simple question here, yet I didn't find a clear answer:
if I want to build a "personal" app for Windows 10 desktop/Windows 10 Mobile, can I do it with UWP? That is, the app would be accessible only by me (and the person whom I give to an *.exe* file or something like this).
Or am I stuck with a WPF app (and I don't know if you can build one for Windows Mobile...).
Thanks,
Benoit

Comment: You can make a app not upload store.Or make a login opeater that only you know the account but need a test account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still upload your app to the Windows store, even if it is for private/personal use.

When opening the *Pricing and availability* settings of your submission, you are able to set the *Distribution and visibility* of your app:

[image]

With this, you can give your friends "promotional codes" - these are way easier to use than explaining your friends sideloading.

Benefits:

- Full control over the persons who will get your app by using one-time promotional codes
- Nice store page, so the persons installing your app will see a preview of what they get
- Automatic updates

Comment: Seems to me the "cleanest" and simplest way to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You can do this, but not with an **.exe** file. You will need to distribute a package (.appx file) and they will be able to install this. This is called **Sideloading**. You can do this by creating an app package in Visual Studio then it will generate a folder and you will need to get the .appx package. Follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that it is the answer! I will test that as soon as I can (I will mark it as the answer aswell).

Comment: FYI: the link you submitted is a bit messed up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

Comment: Ooops. yeah, that's the link that I was trying to share.

Comment: Even if your answer responds exactly at what I asked, in the end the other goes a little beyond, that's why I marked it as the answer. Too bad we can't choose multiple answer...